# NullPointerException at SQLite cursor

Tags: java, android

I received this crash report in my Google Play Console. I never experience such crash on my own device and emulator.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName (PreferenceManager.java:498)
  at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences (PreferenceManager.java:487)
  at DictionaryDB2.getHistoryWords (DictionaryDB2.java)
  or                     .hasObject (DictionaryDB2.java)
```

This is the `getHistoryWords`

```
public List<Bean> getHistoryWords() {
        SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyApp.getAppContext());
        String historyNum = SP.getString("history","50");

        SQLiteDatabase db = initializer.getReadableDatabase();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + HISTORY_NAME +
                " WHERE " + STATUS + " ORDER BY " + STATUS + " DESC LIMIT " + historyNum ;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        List<Bean> wordList = new ArrayList<Bean>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String english = cursor.getString(1);
            String malay = cursor.getString(2);
            wordList.add(new Bean(id, english, malay));
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return wordList;
    }
```

This is `MyApp`:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {  

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "my admob ");
        MyApp.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApp.context;
    }
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: post your `PreferenceManager.java`

Comment: @SantanuSur That's an Android framework class, so not editable by OP. My guess is that this is happening from the statement `SP.getString("history","50");`

Comment: Any information on what sort of device this crash report came from?

Comment: One more thing to add on. I do not receive such crash report before I upgraded my target sdk from 25 to 27

Comment: @MichaelDodd top 2 affected devices are nova 2i (HWRNE), Y7 (HWTRT-Q)

Comment: oops i thot it was his custom class @MichaelDodd :p  ..check your context though..!! :)

Comment: @SantanuSur, I have added `MyPreferencesActivity` and `MyApp` to my question.

Comment: try `return getBaseContext();` instead of `return MyApp.context;` for testing ,this might solve :) in you app class

Comment: @SantanuSur, problem is I can't reproduce this crash and do not know what that will solve the problem.

Comment: Who is calling `getHistoryWords()`?

Comment: @cwbowron, `getHistoryWords()` is called in my `onCreate` of `MainActivity`

Comment: you can try https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/robo-ux-test **robo-test** your screen if its ok then ..its ok.. !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a static reference to the app context inside of `getHistoryWords()`, I would suggest that you add a context parameter, and pass that from the main activity.

```
public List<Bean> getHistoryWords(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    ...
}
```

Then in the main activity...

```
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    setContentView( ... );
    ...
    List<Bean> beans = getHistoryWords( getApplicationContext() );
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have any example of implementation?

Comment: Thank you. I will try whether this solve the problem

Comment: I have published an update to my app with your suggestion. My app has went live for about 24 hours and I do not receive similar crash report. I think this solve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the way you are getting your context for the Preference Manager.

**Problem 1:**

Do not use static references to a Context, I'm pretty sure Android Studio gives you a warning about this.

**Problem 2:**

If you store a Context is a static variable, even if it is the ApplicationContext, if by any chance in case of lack of memory state in your phone, it will be set to null when garbage collector runs.

Just pass the Context to the method you wish to use it and get the application context when you call it

Example:

```
myMethod(getApplicationContext()); // Application context
myMethod(this); //In case you call from Activity
myMethod(getActivity()); //In case you call from Fragment
```

For:

```
public void myMethod(Context context){ ... }
```